Automatically update Person Fields Across SharePoint Lists
I have two SharePoint lists:
1- Students List: Contains student names and basic information, including a lookup field for the course they are enrolled in.
2- Courses List: Contains course names and a "Teacher" field of type "Person or Group."
In the Students List, I added a "Teacher" field of type "Person or Group" because I need to create a filtered view that displays students for each teacher. The filter is set to show records where the "Teacher" equals [Me].
The issue arises when the teacher assigned to a course is changed. I must manually update the "Teacher" field for all students linked to that course.
Is there a non-programmatic way to automate this process so that when the teacher's name is updated in the Courses List, it automatically reflects for all related students in the Students List?
or is there any other way to customize the view So I will not need to fix them manually?
Note: The only tool available to me is SharePoint Designer, but it does not support looping in my version.

What version of SharePoint are you using?

Sharepoint version is 2019, Sharepoint designer is 2013
